# What is wrong with this TreeView and Hierarchical data binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, treeview, hierarchical-data

**Update** see [Simplifying the WPF TreeView ...](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode) for insight on this implementation.

From the bottom:

- base (abstract) class `Folder` in AssemblyA
- subclass `Folder`s in AssemblyB: `BuildFolder`, `Solution`, `Project`
- TreeView in AssemblyC is trying to bind to the hierarchical folder structure

I have a view model `ProjectExplorerVM` that encapsulates `BuildItemVM`. `BuildItemVM` iterates the nested structure of `Folder`s:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

public ObservableCollection<BuildItemVM> Folders {
    get { return folders; }
}

#region constructor
public BuildItemVM(Build Build) : this(Build.RootFolder, null) {
    Name = Build.Name;
}

private BuildItemVM(Folder childFolder, BuildItemVM parentFolder) {
    folderItem = childFolder;
    parentItem = parentFolder;
    Name = folderItem.Name;

    folders = new ObservableCollection<BuildItemVM>(childFolder.Folders
        .Select(f => new BuildItemVM(f, this)));
    folders.CollectionChanged += FoldersCollectionChanged;
}
#endregion
```

`ProjectExplorerVM` is as follows:

```
    #region properties

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    public ReadOnlyCollection<BuildItemVM> RootItems {
        get;
        private set;
    }
    #endregion


    #region constructor
    public ProjectExplorerVM(Build BuildProject) {
        build = BuildProject;
        buildItemVM = new BuildItemVM(build);

        buildItemVM.Folders.CollectionChanged += FoldersCollectionChanged;

        RootItems = new ReadOnlyCollection<BuildItemVM>(new BuildItemVM[] { buildItemVM });
    }
    #endregion
```

... okay, so I've tried many different things that I've found on the google machine. Here is what I have for my binding attempts in the XAML:

```
    <TreeView Name="BuildTree" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <build:BuildFolder x:Key="FolderList"/>

            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type build:BuildFolder}"
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Folders}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type build:Project}"
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Folders}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type build:Solution}"
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Folders}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource FolderList}}"/>
    </TreeView>
```

No nodes appear in the TreeView control. What is wrong with my binding?

Comment: A simple comment will get my attention ... didn't require a down vote. :)

Comment: Wasn't me, I'm not that mean ;)

Comment: @JonathanCarroll: no worries. I forgot to add that simple line at the bottom: no nodes appear in the TreeView. (its updated now)

Comment: @IAbstract I don't see `BuildFolder`, `Project` or `Solution` in your code. I can only see `BuildItemVM`. How does that correspond?

Comment: If I'm seeing right - it seems that you're missing the `ItemsSource` on the `TreeView` itself. As I'm setting up normally - (it's there - scratch this comment :)

Comment: @NSGaga It's down at the bottom.

Comment: ok :) - strange place for that, I didn't see it, thx @EdPlunkett

Comment: Further to @dkozl 's comment, does `BuildFolder` implement any kind of collection interface? Where is there a binding for `ProjectExplorerVM.RootItems`?

Comment: @dkozl: `BuildFolder`, `Project`, `Solution` all inherit `Folder`. As such, each has an `IEnumerable<Folder> Folders` property. That is why I build the `ObservableCollection<BuitItemVM>`. The `IEnumerable` properties shouldn't change to fit the needs of the UI.

Comment: @EdPlunkett: Where/how should I bind `RootItems` ... this is just a part of it that has me confused.

Comment: I don't know where ProjectExplorerVM fits into the whole puzzle. Are those supposed to be the root items of the tree, or are they something unrelated? I'm not sure what you mean when you say "ProjectExplorerVM ... encapsulates BuildItemVM". Subclass? Owner?

Comment: Encapsulation is not inheritance ... essentially yes, owns the BuildItemVM. Polymorphism is tied to inheritance (and sub-classing). See my update for where this implementation is derived.

Comment: @IAbstract Thanks for the remarks about polymorphism, that clears everything right up.

Comment: Using Snoop at runtime can help you identify simple binding errors, fyi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was using an incorrect property name in the binding. So I'm posting the correct binding (Xaml):

```
                <TreeView Name="BuildTree"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding RootItems}">
                    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>

                    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Folders}">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                </TreeView>
```